# Can't view uploaded PDF file in data browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, parse-platform, upload

I uploaded a pdf file to parse and it is visible in the data browser, but when I try to view it it says failed to load.  I believe that my upload code is correct because it works for .docx files but not .pdf.  Any ideas? Here is my code

```
function uploadFile (uploadId,fileName){
var fileUploadControl = $("#fileUpload")[0];
if(fileUploadControl.files.length>0){
    var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];

    var parseFile = new Parse.File(fileName,file);
    parseFile.save().then(function(){
        console.log("nsucciess");
    //file has been saved to parse
    },function(error){
    //file could not be read or saved
        console.log("error");
    });

    //var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    //currentUser.set(fileName,parseFile);

    var ProjectFile = Parse.Object.extend("ProjectFile");
    var projectFile = new ProjectFile();
    projectFile.set("file",parseFile);
    projectFile.save(null,{
        success:function(projectFile){
            console.log("success");
        }
    });
    alert("everything works");
}
else{
    alert("oh no");
}
```

}

Comment: I may be slow, but I can't see where you are trying to `view it`

Comment: in the parse data browser

Comment: @Aaron, same problem working with pdf, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Just solved: you have to add `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=` before the link provided by Parse.com. For example: 
 `var yourUploadedPdfLink = "http://files.parsetfss.com/56accfec-1956-xxxxxx-abe8-xxxxxx/tfss-a7076e9c-xxxx-45fe-a8e8-xxxxxxx-MYDOCUMENT.pdf"` 
 To read it: `"https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + yourUploadedPdfLink`

And it'll works. So, you can't read pdf files clicking on them from Parse.com dashboard (at the moment).